# How do I set the socketTimeout in ktor?

Tags: kotlin, sockets, ktor

I tried

```
val socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp().configure { 
 socketTimeout = 1000 
}.connect("127.0.0.1", 2323)
```

I can set other values like this but not the timeout.
It's listed here [TCPClientSocketOptions](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-network/io.ktor.network.sockets/-socket-options/-t-c-p-client-socket-options/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `socketTimeout` property is an extension of `TCPClientSocketOptions` as you said, but the scope from `configure` provides only `SocketOptions`. In order to correctly configure the TCP socket, you can specify the `socketTimeout` property when calling the `connect` function, like so:

```kotlin
val socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO))
            .tcp()
            .connect("127.0.0.1", 2323) {
                socketTimeout = 1000
            }
```